How to fix: error: package R.id does not exist
I am trying to build old Android/Java code that I wrote 10 years ago.  I have not updated it since I wrote it and I have not programmed anything in Android since then either.  In the code I have several references to R.id.xxxx.  For example:

TextViewListItem        = (TextView)
findViewById(R.id.TextViewListItem);

This code now generates an error when I try to build it:

error: package R.id does not exist

How can I resolve this?  I replaced R.id.xxxx with android.R.id.xxxx and that error went away, but then I get a new error: cannot find symbol android.R.id.whatever.  What would a smart person do?

Check your imports. There are several R packages in android. You should use the one which originates in your project and not in Android, Kotlin/Java or any other packages

How would I use the right R package?  What would the import statement look like?  I'm currently using "import android.R.id", which is what you said not to use.

Okay, I think I figured it out.  I did not modify the import statements.  I did modify the findViewById() statements so they now use a name like com.example.MyExample.R.id.myTextView instead of R.id.myTextView.  That compiled successfully.  Does that sound correct to you?

yes it does sound correct. Congrats

Thank you for helping me solve this.  Since my previous comment, I modified the package statement at the beginning of the file to reflect the correct package name (it was previously set for the package name from 10 years ago).  After doing this, I no longer need to modify the R.id.xxxx entries.  So, it seems the incorrect package name was the real source of this problem.  Thanks again for helping.
